# How to link css file to ejs files

Tags: node.js, express

I am unable to link my css file to any of my ejs files.

My file structure is:

```
public->
------stylesheets->
-----------------main.css
views->
-----campgrounds->
----------------show.ejs
-----partials->
-------------header.ejs
app.js
```

Inside app.js, I'm serving static files in express like:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Inside header.ejs, I'm linking main.css file as:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/main.css'>
```

Inside show.ejs, I am including header.ejs like:

```
<% include ../partials/header %>
```

---

I've tried using in my app.js file

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Comment: There seems nothing wrong with the bits of code you are sharing.
Did you import everything properly and can you check if you set view path and view engine before you set the static file location?

Comment: After you mentioned it, I set the view engine before setting the static file, but it did not fix it.